# Unhandled System.StackOverflowException when using regex in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, regex, validation, datetime

I'm using a regular expression to check the format of a supplied date in my ASP.NET MVC exception. However, every time I run it the action the web server crashes and Visual Studio reports and unhandled System.StackOverflowException

```
//If the supplied date does not match the format yyyy-mm-dd
//Regex taken from www.regexlib.com
if(!Regex.Match(date, "^((((19|20)(([02468][048])|([13579][26]))-02-29))|((20[0-9][0-9])|(19[0-9][0-9]))-((((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))-((0[1-9])|(1\\d)|(2[0-8])))|((((0[13578])|(1[02]))-31)|(((0[1,3-9])|(1[0-2]))-(29|30)))))$").Success)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("Date", "Date is in an invalid format. It must in the format yyyy-mm-dd");
}
```

Has anybody come across this before?

Comment: `//Regex taken from www.regexlib.com` -- That was your second mistake. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a regular expression to check `DateTime` formats, use the [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) method:

> Converts the specified string
>   representation of a date and time to
>   its  DateTime equivalent. The format
>   of the string representation must
>   match a specified format exactly. **The
>   method returns a value that indicates
>   whether the conversion succeeded.**

Here is an example of how to use it:

```
DateTime dateTime;

if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(
    yourString, 
    "yyyy-MM-dd", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
    DateTimeStyles.None, 
    out dateTime))
{
     ModelState.AddModelError(
         "Date", 
         "Date is in an invalid format. It must in the format yyyy-mm-dd");
}
```

I am not sure why your regular expression is creating problems but I think it would be best to avoid the problem all together here by using the proper solution for `DateTime` validation.

Comment: D'oh! I'd used that method somewhere else before too. Don't know why I didn't think to use it here. Thanks.